# How to check only persian character in string by php

Tags: php

How to check only persian character in string by php?

see below

```
string valid : persian character

string invalid : except persian character(contain: latin && {&*%$ ,....})
```

Comment: I Persian known as something else? Perhaps one these languages, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php? Can you add samples of a valid and invalid string?

Comment: valid : خلیج همیشه فارس
|||  invalid : persian gulf   
||| invalid : خلیج همیشگی persian
|||  invalid :  خلیج همیشگی فارس *

Answer (score 0):

```php
$alphabet = ['الف', 'بِ', 'پِ', '...']; # create an array that contains only Persian characters
$alphabet = array_flip($alphabet);    # reverse the array (key <=> value)

$chars = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string); # use this regexp to transform string intro array of chars

foreach ($chars as $char)
{
    if (!isset($alphabet[$char])) # use isset to check the char in the aplhabet
    {
        # it's not Persian character!
    }
}
```

Comment: If the OP has all the persian characters a character class and `preg_match` would be much easier. e.g. https://regex101.com/r/uHrtNU/1/

Comment: chris85 thanks .. is work. very good. خلیج همیشگی فارس